# Remove from scrape

Tags: php, preg-replace, web-scraping

Hey all,
I've successfully created a website scraper getting the top 40 from the record industry website, however one of the columns in the table I'm scraping might sometimes not be there. Basically what I need is a way to remove any instances of this from my scrape:

```
<td><img src="/images/bullet_red.gif" width="8" height="8" title="Red Dot" /></td>
```

Here's what I've got from a tutorial so far.

```
$url = "http://www.ariacharts.com.au/pages/charts_display_singles.asp?chart=1U50";
$raw = file_get_contents($url);
$newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");

$content = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($raw));

$start = strpos($content,'<table class="chartTable"');
$end = strpos($content,'</table>',$start) + 8;

$table = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|U",$table,$rows);

foreach ($rows[0] as $row){

if ((strpos($row,'<th')===false)){

    preg_match_all("|<td(.*)</td>|U",$row,$cells);

    $number = strip_tags($cells[0][1]);

    $name = strip_tags($cells[0][5]);

    $artist = strip_tags($cells[0][6]);

    $name = strtolower($name);
    $name = ucwords($name);

    echo "{$artist} - {$name} - Number {$number} <br>\n";

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser instead of complex regex http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.ariacharts.com.au/pages/charts_display_singles.asp?chart=1U50');
$table = $html->find('table.chartTable');

foreach ($table[0]->find('tr') as $row) {
    $columns = $row->find('td');
    if (sizeof($columns) < 7) continue;

    $number = $columns[1]->plaintext;
    $name = ucwords($columns[6]->plaintext);
    $artist = $columns[7]->plaintext;

    echo "$artist - $name - Number $number <br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just looking for how to remove a single line, not rewrite the whole script. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sam, you need to learn to take good advice when its offered. See my updated post with how much easier it is to use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. It achieves what you want in about 50% of the code you had. PS: You should not use regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: @Petah, use cURL with Simple HTML DOM Parser instead of file_get_contents()... http://webarto.com/82/php-simple-html-dom-curl @Sam, you should delete your script, and start over, you cannot parse HTML this complex with RegEx's (you shouldn't).

Comment: @webarto, while cURL might be slightly better, it makes no real difference. Also I was answering in the context of the question, he used file_get_contents, so I used the equivalent. For all we know he has cURL disabled.

Comment: Just for reference, I was using this tutorial: http://www.bradino.com/php/screen-scraping/. My knowledge of screen scraping and preg_match & preg_replace is limited, thus why I asked here.

Comment: Regardless, I tried your code and I am getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object".

Comment: @sam, on what line?, that means that either the html didnt load, or it was not in the structure you expected. I tested this on that website and it worked fine.

Comment: Line 4 '$table = $html->find('table.chartTable');'

Answer (score 1):

For the quick and dirty method you want, put this code before you declare the "start" variable:

```
$content = str_replace('<td><img src="/images/bullet_red.gif" width="8" height="8" title="Red Dot" /></td>', '', $content);
```